# Prove the the orthocentre of a triangle which is incribed in a circle is inside of the concentric circle of 3 times radius.

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

The question is : 
Let C and C' be two concentric circles in the plane with radii  R  & 3R respectively. Show that the orthocentre of any triangle inscribed in circle C lies in the interior of circle C'.
It is a good problem I believe . In observation we can easily see that It is true because C' is a very big circle but in which way we can solve it I need some help..
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to exploit [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line). We know that $O,G,H$ (circumcenter, centroid, orthocenter) are always collinear and $HO=3 OG$. Let $O$ be the circumcenter of our triangle, i.e. the centre of $C$. The centroid of our triangle lies inside such a triangle, hence in the interior of $C$.
 It follows that $H$ lies in the interior of $3C=C'$.