# To prove orthocenter of triangle inscribed incircle of radius r lies in cocentric circle of radius 3r

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two concentric circles in the plane with radii $R$ and $3R$ respectively. Show
that the orthocentre of any triangle inscribed in circle $C_1$ lies in the interior of circle $C_2$.
Conversely, show that also every point in the interior of $C_2$ is the orthocentre of some triangle
inscribed in $C_1$.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please edit to show so.

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as here: [Prove orthocenter of triangle lying in circle of radius r lies inside concentric circle of radius 3r](https://mathoverflow.net/q/285540) and [Prove the the orthocentre of a triangle which is incribed in a circle is inside of the concentric circle of 3 times radius.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1942218).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Indeed, but not quite a duplicate because the other question lacks the converse.

Answer (score 0):

For equilateral triangle circumcenter, centroid , orthocenter coincides ,for right triangles orthocenter is on circum circle ,for obtuse triangles is between r to 3r and for other triangles it is inside circumcircle.
Points circumcenter(c), centroid(g) and orthocenter(h) are collinear g divides ch in 1:2 so when g lies on circumcircle g is 3r from c.
But when it comes to converse we see points between circle(3r) - circle(r) are swept by rotating that collinear line by symmetry which is allowed as by rotating line triangli will rotate on center will not violate requirements

Comment: Please comment want to check if my work is lame or better way to work it is there